# Automate (IE ComObject) Fill Textboxes

Tags: html, internet-explorer, powershell, automation, comobject

I'm Trying to Automate a Outlook Web Access website, fill some textboxes and click a buttons,

I can find the relevant elements in the first page(sign-in) and the submit button, so i pass the login phase, my problem is to find the elements inside some page with masked textboxes, i attached a snapshots of the 3 steps, and also the DOM image of the object.

[image: The Login Page]

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$URL = 'https://somewebsite/ecp/?rfr=owa&p=PersonalSettings/Password.aspx'
$IE.Visible = $true
$IE.Navigate($URL)
While ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000} 

$ie.Document.getElementById('username').value = "username"
$ie.Document.getElementById('password').value = "password"
$Submit = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('Input') | ? {$_.Type -eq "Submit"}
$Submit.click()
```

so far so good, my problem start in the pages inside, i just can't find the textboxes elements for the password fields,

[image]

also here's the DOM snapshot for those elements:

[image]

I'm really appreciate any help

Comment: You can use WASP for PowerShell [link](https://wasp.codeplex.com) .
Import the module. Once on a page close to where you need to go you could use 
$IE | Send-Keys "{TAB}"
a set amount of times to navigate through the webpage to get where you want.

Comment: wasp is not an option, should be run on multiple systems, WShell.SendKey is not an option as wel, not stable at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same sort of problem when trying to [automate a file upload on sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209227/using-internetexplorer-object-what-is-the-correct-way-to-wait-for-an-ajax-respon) .
The trick was that the upload form was open inside a new frame.

```
<iframe id="Dlg..." class="ms-dlgFrame" src="https://.../Upload.aspx?List=..."></iframe>
```

So to get the input fields I had to look into each open frames and select the one with the good location :

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $ie.Document.frames.length;$i++){
   if( $ie.Document.frames.item($i).location.href -match 'upload.aspx' ){
       $frm=$ie.Document.frames.item($i)}
 }
```

from then I was able to target the input field:

```
$frm.document.body.getElementById("txtOldPwd")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with Using UI Automation.there we can easily detect the element using the Automation ID and we can easily perform Read/Write operation's.But i don't know whether your are comfortable using UI automation,if its fine then i think i can help you out.
there are many opetion in UI automation such as

1)UI automation.

2)White

3)watin.etc.,

if you are comfortable with any of the framework then i think i can help you out.

Comment: U just once go through the Following Links for Getting Brief idea :             UI Path: [http://www.uipath.com/]   <br/>                                                          UI Automation: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx]                                                      White :[https://github.com/TestStack/White]                                        Watin: [http://watin.org/]

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it :)

The problem was that the site has two `iframe` tags, one inside the other,

```
$IFrame = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').item(0)
$IFrame = $IFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').item(0)
$PasswordSlab = $IFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('passwordSlab')
$PasswordSlab.document.getElementById('txtOldPwd').value = $OldPassword
$PasswordSlab.document.getElementById('txtNewPwd').value = $NewPassword
$PasswordSlab.document.getElementById('txtConfirmPwd').value = $NewPassword
$PasswordSlab.document.getElementById('save').click()
```

Thanks for everybody